# how to make a div come to the top of screen jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several divs.

When the user clicks a button for a certain div which is half way down the page to be positioned centre so the top of the div is more like at the top of the page.

how do i do this using jquery?

Comment: I really dont understand your question .... what should happen when the button is click ? scroll ? animation ? a `DIV` appears ?

Comment: sorry yeh just want the page to scroll down so the div at the bottom is in the center of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#button").click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
     }, 2000);
 });
```

Also see [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)